# PyJWT: Decoding token throws AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, apple-push-notifications, pyjwt

For context, I am attempting to create a JWT used to send notification requests to Apple Push Notifications server, as described [here](https://gist.github.com/Hiyorimi/41bc8cf1fb913cb9eb3f70d6e9587f5d) and [here](https://gist.github.com/ArchieR7/500a3831f14ef4c88987659854ae99f3). Following the gists, I've attempted to decode the token generated by the `jwt.encode()` method. I wasn't sure why the gists did this, because [PyJWT Docs](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) state this method returns a `str`. In fact, the top answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798281/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-python-error) points this out.

However, if I don't attempt to decode the token, I receive a `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable` when I attempt to package the token as a request header:

```
def generate_token() -> str:
    token = jwt.encode(
        {...}
    )

    return token

def push_notification():
    auth_token = generate_token()
    headers = {"authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}"}
    ...
    response = await client.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload) # Traceback TypeError here
```

Note that the `payload` argument contains a dictionary of strings, there are no bytes here:

```
    payload_data = {
        "aps": {
            "alert": {
                "title": "Air Quality Alert",
                "subtitle": "Your Air Quality Has recently exceeded WHO guidelines",
                "body": "This is a test notification"
            },
            "sound": "default",
            "category": "AIR_QUALITY",
            "interruption-level": "active"
        },
    }

    payload = json.dumps(payload_data).encode('utf-8')
```

As the title of the question states, if I do attempt to decode the token then an `AttributeError` is thrown: `str' object has no attribute 'decode'`:

```
"authorization":f"bearer{auth_token.decode('ascii')}" 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Looks like it used to be `bytes`: https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/pull/521#issuecomment-760677034 , https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/commit/5d33b041f2aeccc653436958c08187f1bd538d94

Comment: Please be aware that you are here `f"bearer{auth_token.decode('ascii')}"`running into the next problem, because there should be a space between "Bearer" (usually with uppercase B) and the token., eg. "Bearer eyJ....". Right now the space is missing.

Comment: @jps The error output in the console strips the whitespace, but excellent eye and I have fixed the capitalization. Thank you.